# Binding data synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

Are the binding functions synchronous at knockout.js?
Would I get always the data in my `getDeliveryNote` function in this example?

```
function myModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.orders = ko.observable();

    self.selectAndClick = function(data){
        self.orders(data);
        self.getDeliveryNote();
    }

    self.getDeliveryNote(){
        console.log(self.orders()); // would i ALWAYS get the data here?
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. What led you to believe this wouldn't work?

Comment: @CrimsonChris just want to make sure they are synchronous calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything will be updated synchronously. Yes, `getDeliveryNote` will always contain the data you set with `self.orders(data);`

You could consider using a `ko.computed` here so that `deliveryNote` depends on `orders`, then you wouldn't need to call `getDeliveryNote` at all.
eg.

```
self.deliveryNote=ko.computed(function(){
    //...using orders() inside this function will cause 'deliveryNote'
    //...to be reevaluated when the value of 'orders' changes
    //...(ie this function will be called
    //...when orders(data) is called with a different 'data' from last time)

    return orders().deliveryNote() // for example

    });
```

Now you can use `deliveryNote()` and it will always be in sync with what is in orders.

Then you also wouldn't need the `selectAndClick` function because you would bind directly to `orders` instead.

Comment: Awesome! :) Thanks for it.